# Why do I get an empty newline with fgets()

Tags: c

```
    argv0 = "delreves";

    int m;
    for(m = 1;m < argc;m++){
        char buffer[256];       
        FILE *fd;
        fd = fopen(argv[m],"r"); 
        if(fd==NULL){
            Error (EX_NOINPUT, "%s", "Fallo");
        }   
        while(fgets(buffer,256,fd)){
            int size = strlen(buffer);

            int l=size-1;
            int j;              
            for(j = 0; j < size/2; j++, l--){
                        char temp = buffer[j];
                    buffer[j] = buffer[l];
                    buffer[l] = temp;
            }
        printf("%s",buffer);            
        }

    fclose(fd);

    }

}
```

After running the program with a days of week file I have

```
./a.out file.txt

yadnom
yadseut
....
```

---

How can I eliminate the empty newline before the first day?

Answer (score 3):

The function `fgets` is returning the string ending with the newline character, if encountered in the input file. Your algorithm is reversing the string, preserving the newline, so it is coming as a first character of the output. An this is what you see: newline and then the string. If you want to eliminate it, just discard the last character of the input (replace it with `\0`), or work with length-1.